# .mesh files in Blender

Tags: import, file-format

Does anyone know if there is a way to import a .mesh filo into blender? I got some files from a game and i would like to look at them and maybe edit them. I tried some things suggested on the internet but they didn't work. If there isn't one, is there another program that can open those files?[image]

Comment: https://fileinfo.com/extension/mesh
https://www.meshconvert.com/
Some links that you may find useful if you haven't checked them before

Comment: Thank you. But Medit seems to be something else and I am currently downloading godot.

Comment: meshconvert.com gives me an error message when I try it

Comment: It's probably unsupported, has godot finished downloading for you?

Comment: Nope. I have slow internet. but I hope that I can open it with godot

Comment: The good thing is that godot is a really small program so hopefully it doesn't take too long

Comment: It stoppped downloading and I didn't notice it. I downloadeed it but it doesn't work with .mesh files. I found something called Ogre Mesh Viewer that I will try next. https://sourceforge.net/projects/ogremeshviewer/